# Why Convert.ToInt32 or Int32.Parse do not work for me?

Tags: c#, .net, integer

It should be a simple code:

```
        string qty = "211.0000";
        Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(qty));
```

I tried to use `Convert.ToInt32` or `Int32.Parse`, but they all throw an error:
Error(s):
Exception in user code:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)    at Rextester.Program.Main(String[] args)

Did I make any errors to define a string and give a value? I have tried use `string` or `String` to define the variable. It works if I use `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32("211.0000"))`.

BTW I was testing in http://rextester.com/

Comment: `"211.0000"` is not a valid *integer* value but a *floating point* one.

Comment: Because it's not an integer

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko But I was trying to define it as a string first by using double quotes, and then convert it to int. At least Convert.ToInt32 should works isn't it?

Comment: Integers don't have '.' characters in them

Comment: @Rufus L I am sorry I am confused, shouldn't both of Convert.ToInt32 or Int32.Parse are convert string to number?

Comment: @JamesChen They do, but only if the string follows the correct *format*. Integers cannot contain decimal points, therefore you cannot parse it as an Int32.

Comment: @James Only if the string can be converted will they work. Just as you cannot convert "123A000" to an integer, you cannot convert "123.000" to an integer (using those functions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When working with *floating point* values (which have explicit decimal separator `.`) you should use `decimal` or `double`:

```
  using System.Globalization;

  ...

  string qty = "211.0000";

  // be careful: different cultures have different decimal separators
  decimal result = decimal.Parse(qty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
  double result = double.Parse(qty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

having got floating point representation you can round it up to integer

```
  int value = (int) (result > 0 ? result + 0.5 : result - 0.5);
```

or

```
  int value = (int) (Math.Round(result));
```

Comment: wow didn't know it was that tricky to convert a string of double into integer in C#...

Comment: Why not just call `Math.Round`?

Comment: @hvd: sorry, bad habit from pure `C`...

Answer (score 2):

I'm changing my answer, hope that's ok, but here's probably the best thing for you is to do a `decimal.TryParse`, which can handle leading characters like `-` and `.`, and then just cast the result to an integer. If the parsing fails, it returns a zero (in the case where the string is not a decimal):

```
decimal result;
Console.WriteLine(decimal.TryParse(qty, NumberStyles.Any, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result) ? (int)result : 0);
```

The same code could be used to store the int for later use:

```
decimal result;
int intResult = decimal.TryParse(qty, NumberStyles.Any,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result) ? (int) result : 0;
```

Comment: A bit wierd, but counter example: `".123"` expected output `0`, actual - exception

Comment: As I said, you need to have a valid integer in front of the '.' character.

Comment: Updated answer with an example of padding the string with a leading '0' in case it starts with a decimal

Comment: Now a negative number, e.g. `"-1"` is a counter example...

Comment: Ok, I've changed the answer entirely :)

Comment: please, add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` - "it gives me 2110000, but I want 211" (see comments on Roxy'Pro's answer)

Comment: Ok, I changed it to use InvariantCulture and provided a solution that will also return `0` if the parsing fails (like if you pass it `"hello"`)

Answer (score 1):

The value you provided is not an integer, before everything what you might try is converting it to a decimal and after that use `Convert.ToInt32` from `mscorlib` because Integers cannot contain decimal points, soo that means you cannot parse it as an Int32, please follow next example:

```
string value = String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
decimal d = decimal.Parse(value);
Convert.ToInt32(d);
```

Comment: it gives me 2110000, but I want 211

Comment: @JamesChen check for edit

Comment: @JamesChen If you do not specify culture info (`IFormatProvider`), the current one will be used. On `rextester.com` that will be _German (Germany)_. Therefore a comma is required if you want a decimal separator. So `decimal.Parse("211,0000")` will give `211` with that culture, while `decimal.Parse("211.0000")` gives `2110000`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Decimal` instead of `int`

```
Decimal.Parse(qty);
```

If you just need the integer part then use the following snippet

```
Double.Parse(qty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: it gives me 2110000, but I want 211...

Comment: Just edited my answer, it will give you the desired results.

Comment: still 2110000...

Comment: How come `Double.Parse(qty)` gives you 2110000? It gives me 211.

Comment: @JamesChen By any chance is your program running with a locale which interprets "." as a thousands separator and "," as a fraction separator (e.g. one of numerous European locales)?

Comment: 'string qty = "211.0000"; Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse(qty));' Right? I really get 2110000, and i am pretty sure i was using dot...

Comment: @JamesChen Try the edited version with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: sorry i saw Dmitry Bychenko comes up first of that solution, so i will select him :-)